# Get Rails working on Darwin 14.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gcc

I tried to install Rails on a Mac Darwin 14.3 Yosemite. I followed the Instructions on [Railsapp](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html). My problems start with gcc. Although everything is in the right place: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
'gcc' is not working. i just get back "clang: error: no input files"
what can i possibly do?

Comment: what gcc command are you using? Also, you can't just use `gcc` as a command unto itself. It's a C compiler and needs files to create object files. If you want to just check if it exists, use `gcc --version`

Comment: tried that and it gave me the same 'clang error'back.

Comment: i was just trying to follow the aforementioned guide to a rails-installment. could you have a look at the guide and tell me, if it is all wrong and I am wasting my time with it?

Comment: That's one hell of a long guide.

Answer (score 0):

Well, installing rails is usually quite straightforward.

- Step 1: install [homebrew](http://brew.sh) `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
- Step 2: Install [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`
- Step 3: Install Ruby
- Step 4: Install bundler (`gem install bundler`)
- Step 5: Install rails (`gem install rails`)